# Lightbox gallery

Tags: gallery

Maybe someone can give any tips how to make lightbox gallery for CraftCMS?

```
{% set gallery = entry.gallery.all() %}
 <div class="columns is-multiline is-mobile py-3">
 {% for gallery in entry.gallery.all() %}
  <div class="column is-3-desktop is-6-mobile is-6-tablet">
<img class="is-cutted-half" src="{{ gallery.url() }}">
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I need this thing to display in lightbox with ability to get prev/next image as well.. Anyone have tips on this?

Comment: Which lightbox are you using?